# How to convert the number into Month using expression language?

Tags: apache-nifi

I get an integer and I need to convert to a month names using expression language in nifi

```
Example for locale en-us:
1 -> Jan
2 -> Feb
3 -> Mar
```

How can i convert the number into month in nifi using expression language?

Comment: If you're hoping to do this with nothing but regex, sorry, but that's impossible. Regex isn't a silver bullet for find and replace - it simply isn't designed to have different replacements for different matches.

Comment: @Addison i doesn't mean regex i just mean expression language only.

Comment: Right - The regex tag threw me off. Was probably meant to be `Expression Language` then?

Comment: @Addison Thanks for your reply. i mean Expression language in below link.
https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html#type_cast

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this with a date parsing and formatting expression like the one below.  For example, if your attribute `monthnum` is 2:

```
${monthnum:toDate("MM"):format("MMM")}
```

Would yield `Feb`.  But I don't think it will let you control the locale, it is using the machine default.  Another approach would be a text lookup:

```
${literal('Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec'):getDelimitedField(${monthnum})}
```